# Using MouseHover event and ToolTip

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

To show the relevant information(in monopoly game, the property belongs which player, current market price  etc.), I put a Label on the top of a panel, and used a ToolTip object to display the information. This is the image of my current setup.
[image]

Here are the steps I have done:
1.Added MouseHover event handler  (The Label name is MEDITERANEAN)

```
this.MEDITERANEAN.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.MEDITERANEAN_MouseHover);
```

2.Initialized Tooltip

```
private void InitializeToolTip()
        {
            toolTipLabel.ToolTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;
            toolTipLabel.IsBalloon = true;
            toolTipLabel.ShowAlways = true;
        }
```

3.Call setToolTip() in MouseHover call back function

```
private void MEDITERANEAN_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            toolTipLabel.SetToolTip(MEDITERANEAN, "You put mouse over me");
            rolledDice.AppendText("Mouse Over");
        }
```

But when I start application and move my cursor over the label, there is no text from toolTipLabel. What part did I make mistakes?

Interestingly, i made other function and it works.

```
private void panelBoard_MouseOver(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            toolTipLabel.SetToolTip(panelBoard, "You put mouse over me");
            rolledDice.AppendText("Mouse Over");
        }
```

Comment: image is inside panel ? and label is over image ?

Comment: have you tried `toolTipLabel.SetToolTip(this.MEDITERANEAN, "You put mouse over me");`

Comment: @zey image is the background of the panelBoard, label in over the panel board

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to bring your `lable control` in front of image. Try something like this .

```
MEDITERANEAN.BringToFront();
```

Comment: I did what you suggested, I put it in both constructors I made.It's still not working.

Comment: your `lable` has text ? Try put some text in this lable and re-run . And check if the lable's text appear or not .

Comment: and also , you should set label's Autosize property to false

Comment: thanks for reply, I did try to put text in it and rerun-ed, but it's still not working. the label's Autosize property is false,I noticed that when I run, the label text is missing

Comment: so the text you put in lable shows correctly in position you want ?

Comment: I just did re-run the program, the text I put in label is not showing

Comment: I recon, even I called the function label.BringtoFront(), the label is not in front of the panel

Comment: I set the label Visibility property to true, it showed the text. But the colour of text is grey, and the mouseHover call back function is still not called.

Comment: put breakpoint inside `MEDITERANEAN_MouseHover` and check if this event fire correctly , @C.Mi , your code should work.

Comment: Thanks, I set Panel's property "Enable" to true, and MEDITERANEAN_MouseHover is called correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, first I should set Panel's property "Enable" to true, then set label's property "visible" to true as well.